# PHP - Get value of XML node

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I have an XML file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeteBayDetailsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2012-07-04T13:54:51.873Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>779</Version>
  <Build>E779_CORE_BUNDLED_14986049_R1</Build>
  <SiteDetails>
    <Site>US</Site>
    <SiteID>0</SiteID>
    <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
    <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
  </SiteDetails>
  <SiteDetails>
    <Site>Canada</Site>
    <SiteID>2</SiteID>
    <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
    <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
  </SiteDetails>
</GeteBayDetailsResponse>
```

I am trying to find a way to get the value of the SiteID node where the Site node equals whatever.

I have tried using XPath and DomDocument functions but without any luck.  Some of the messed up code is below:

```
    $xml_file ='SiteDetails.xml';
    $xmlDoc = new DomDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load($xml_file);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($xmlDoc);

    $xpath->registerNamespace('ebay', 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');

    //$siteIDList = $xpath->query("/ebay:GeteBayDetailsResponse/ebay:SiteDetails[ebay:Site='UK']/ebay:SiteID");
    //$siteIDList =  $xpath->query("/GeteBayDetailsResponse/SiteDetails[Site=\"UK\"]/SiteID");

//$siteIDList =  $xpath->query("//*[namespace-uri()='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents' and name()='Site' and text()='$site']/following-sibling::*[namespace-uri()='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents' and name()='SiteID']/text()");

    //var_dump($siteIDList);
    //echo $siteIDList->item(0)->nodeValue;

            /*$SiteDetails = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('SiteDetails');
            $count = 0;
            foreach($SiteDetails as $details){
            //  print_r($details);
            echo $details->nodeValue;
                if ($details->nodeValue == $site){
                    echo 'YEAH';
                    echo $details->SiteID;
                }
            $count ++;  
            }*/
            //$siteID = $siteIDNode->item(8)->nodeValue;        

    //var_dump($siteIDNode);
}
```

Can anyone help?  As you can see from the above, I am confused...

Comment: Can you clarify: You want to get `SiteID` from **a specific** `SiteDetails` node where `Site` node equals X? For example given "Canada" you want to get "2"?

Comment: yeah thats it exactly. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general idea is that you iterate over each `SiteDetails` node and check the `Site` node value against the value you are looking for.

Assuming `$xml` contains your xml as [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instance

```
$site = 'Canada';
$siteId = null;

foreach($xml->SiteDetails as $sd) {
  if(((string)$sd->Site) === $site) {
    $siteId = (int)$sd->SiteID;
    //break;
  }
}

var_dump($siteId); //int(2)
```

[Here is a working example on codepad](http://codepad.org/zGDDXtFY)

### Solution using xpath()

Here is a solution using [`xpath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ebay','urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');
$site = 'Canada';
$siteId = $xml->xpath('ebay:SiteDetails/ebay:Site[text()="'.$site.'"]/../ebay:SiteID');
echo (string)$siteId[0]; //2
```

[working example in codepad](http://codepad.org/IU5jmlGX)

Explanation:

1. First we find `SiteDetails` node with child node `Site` with value "Canada" (or any other value in `$site`) by using `text()` function of xpath which returns the value of the element.
2. Then we go to the corresponding father `SiteDetails` by using `..` xpath selector.
3. Lastly we extract the value of `SiteID` from the needed `SiteDetails` element.

Good luck =)

Comment: Ive tried to go with the 2nd option usin Xpath and I get "Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array" error, when I do a var_dump I get an empty object.  THis is the same result as I got from my code above.  I will try the first option.

Comment: @LeeTee Try to use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead of DOMNodeList, this should work.